# Populating request.DATA for testing api in Django using APIRequestFactory

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

I am using restframeworks test modules to write test. I need to test a get request for which I created a test as follows

```
    class BlogCommentTest(APISimpleTestCase):
        def test_3002_getting_reviewcomment(self):
             factory = APIRequestFactory()
             request = factory.get(reverse('get-review-comments'), data= {"article": 1})
             request.user = self.user
             view = ReviewCommentViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})


             force_authenticate(request, self.user)
             response = view(request)
```

however the way I wrote populates the request.GET with {'article':1} when I want to populate request.DATA. What is the correct way to make the request object whose request.DATA is populated the way I want ?

**EDIT**
The code for viewset is

```
    class ReviewCommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    viewset to get recursive serialized results
    """
    model = models.ReviewComments
    serializer_class = serializers.ReviewCommentSerializer
    queryset = models.ReviewComments.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)

    def serialize_tree(self, queryset):
        """
        :return: A helper function to get list of next set of childrens
        """
        for obj in queryset:
            data = self.get_serializer(obj).data
            data['parent'] = self.serialize_tree(obj.children.all().exclude(is_deleted=True))
            yield data

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(parent=None, article=request.DATA['article'])
        data = self.serialize_tree(queryset)
        return Response(data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        data = self.serialize_tree([self.object])
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: I am not getting what are you actually testing here in this test case?

Comment: I was testing a view named ReviewCommentViewSet in my views.py which uses request.DATA to fetch the comments realted to that article.

Comment: Please post the viewset code where you are using `request.DATA`. Also, use `request.data` instead as `request.DATA` is pending deprecation.

Comment: Also, `.get()` with a `data` dictionary results in the evaluation of a GET request equivalent to `/my/url/?article=1`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get

Comment: @rahul-gupta I will read about request.DATA and request.data and will convert code to request.data. Actually I want to imitate the following curl request.  `curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"article": "7bicp2zCsxJn0ap"}' http://test.com:8000/v1.0/comments/review/get/`